# Connectivity issues with Wi-Fi Direct

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am developing a peer-to-peer Android game. For that I am using **Wi-Fi Direct** to establish a connection between two devices. I am able to establish the connection. I have followed the *Google documentation* to set up the connection.

**Issue:** User A can send a connection request to User B. User B responds to that request by accepting or rejecting it. User A is not able get any response to the connection request when User B denies the connection request.

To solve this problem, I have started 20sec timer at User A’s end (sender) whenever User A sends a request to User B. Also, I want to start the timer at user B’s end when a connection request arrives. Now, I am not able to figure out how to start the timer at receiver ends when a request arrives.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to recognize an arrival of a connection request at receiver’s end?
2. How to handle the response to connection request at User A’s end (sender), when User B denies the connection request?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void connect(int position, final String name) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"connecting "+name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final WifiP2pDevice device=peers.get(position);
    WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
    config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
    mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"connected to "+ device.deviceName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            isConnected=1;
            mDiscover.setText("disconnect");
            //success logic
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error :"+ reason,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //failure logic
        }
    });
}
```

this method connections with peers if the request is declined or get into some error than onFaliure will be called with reason code.

Comment: No, it wont tell us about the request denial. It tells about whether the request is successfully send or not.